# Why is mixing ratio at LCL not the same as for starting condition?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling, python, metpy, condensation

I asked a question regarding mixing ratio and wet adiabatic lifting in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76244447/why-is-mixing-ratio-at-lcl-not-the-same-as-for-starting-condition.

I don't want to create a redundant copy of this question, but maybe the question can be answered here better than in the other community.

Is it a problem in the python library or did I make a mistake in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has been answered in the other community: The discrepany is due to a different definition of relative humidity as used in the metpy function `mixing_ratio_from_relative_humidity`.

See also: https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/2951